# Stochastic variables in pymc

Tags: python, distribution, pymc, mcmc, stochastic

I have come across such terms as

```
runiform, rbinomial etc
```

at many places .

I couldn't find about them anywhere. I can only see their usage.

What do they denote and how they are different from `uniform, binomial` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyMC2, functions like `runiform` and `rbinomial` with the distribution names with `r` in front are (pseudo-) random number generators for the distribution, i.e. `rbinomial(100, .5)` returns a random draw from Binomial(100,.5).  These functions have a `size` parameter, which specifies how many draws to return:

```
In [3]: pm.rbinomial(100, .5, size=10)
Out[3]: array([54, 49, 57, 47, 39, 54, 52, 45, 52, 54])
```

You may also be interested in functions like `Uniform` and `Binomial`, which return pymc.Stochastic objects, suitable for including in Bayesian models, and functions like `uniform_like` and `binomial_like`, which return the log-likelihood of the respective distributions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on functions like uniform_like with some example. If I am not wrong, I can use logp on even functions like Uniform and Binomial. A resource with their usage will also work.

Comment: Sure, here is a little example: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/0d7e1c5084ef5a399b32